# Unable to reach server via local IP, only "localhost"

Tags: network, catalina

For years I've been able to use my local IP to access local servers during development.  e.g. http://192.168.80.20:3000. It seems that after updating to macOS 10.15.4 this is no longer possible.  I can only access my projects with localhost e.g. http://localhost:3000. This is fine for when I am using a local client such as Chrome or iOS Simulator, but I also need to do testing across my local network from another device.  I'm not sure what changed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure NodeJS is listening on all interfaces.

- `:3000`
- `localhost:3000`
- `[::]:3000`
- `127.0.0.1:3000`

All the above are different but all are listening on port 3000. Only the first `:3000` listens to every interface: IPv4, IPv6, and other interfaces like ethernet and WiFi.

Use `sudo lsof -i` show which ports, interfaces, and protocols your server is listening to.